# Javascript/Flash tiny, cross-browser sound player

Tags: javascript, flash, audio

I was searching for Javascript/Flash tiny, cross-browser sound player (notifier), but every solution I've met was or too big and feature-full, or based on different libraries (not on Jquery I'm using), or with bugs. The only feature I need is 'play'. :)

For example, http://flash-mp3-player.net/players/js/download/ - this nice little player does not work in Firefox (SetVariable issue).

I'm working on it almost for 3 days and nights. )

Please recommend tiny, cross-browser implementation. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [SoundManager 2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/), allegedly used by last.fm and soundcloud.

Answer (score 2):

What about Dew Player http://www.alsacreations.fr/dewplayer.html

Comment: I found that soundmanager has many more faults and errors in it, but dewplayer works way better. The only catch is that it is a French application.

Comment: Excuse me but, why would it be a catch?

Comment: Well, it is a bit hard navigating around the pages.

Comment: Dew Player is not currently available. The Web site says that it will "be reborn" "when it's done".

Answer (score 1):

Maybe html5-based plugin would be good for notifications, check out this https://stackoverflow.com/a/9690139/1889306