# Is it possible to play a quick chime in website without a plugin (no Flash or Quicktime)?

Tags: javascript, flash, audio

I have a single page web app that shows real time data using just HTML/CSS/JS -  I have managed to keep Flash out of it.

Now I want to play a small chime but I don't want to make the site dependent on Flash.  It is just a chime to indicate a new chat, so it is not a huge stumbling block but I would like to find a way.

Is this possible - I am guessing no since you need something local to play the sound, but I am hoping here!

Thanks in advance for any help!

**Edit:** I am not able to use HTML5 quite yet.

Comment: I would use javascript to make a hidden embed.

Comment: If only `echo chr(7)` would work in browsers... good old ctrl-g to the rescue.

Comment: @CoffeeRain Could you explain?  Embed what?

Comment: It seems that it isn't possible without some sort of plugin, or HTML 5.  I will leave it open for awhile to see if anyone else comes up with something.  I appreciate all of the answers - I may need to use Flash for this after all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the HTML5 audio framework [buzz](http://buzz.jaysalvat.com/) or [MediaElement.JS](http://mediaelementjs.com/)

Comment: Thanks ... I can't go to HTML 5 just yet - I need to support IE 8.

Comment: @MattW Hack for browser X, Y, and HTML 5 for Z ;-) [But in more seriousness, look at HTML 5 "compatibility" layers, this might already be supported.] Also, Buzz says it "degrades gracefully", not sure if that implies "tries internal work-abouts" or not.

Comment: @pst Ha - the answer for most javascript questions, it seems.  Thanks - I will keep at it.

Comment: @MattW You may want to test the demo in ie8. It doesn't explicitly say that ie8 is supported however it says it degrades gracefully for non-modern browsers which means it probably supports it.

Comment: You can check http://buzz.jaysalvat.com/documentation/sound/ and test each format(IE supports only mp3 with this framework.)

Comment: This is the best answer I saw.  It uses HTML5 which may cause problems for others.

Answer (score 2):

Playing .wav files embedded in html?  Try [Different ways to play sound from a website - UCL](http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/mark/audio/play6.htm)

Comment: That seems to be using Quicktime - which I am also trying to avoid.  I know it wasn't part of the question - I guess I should have said no plugin, rather than no Flash.

Answer (score 0):

Example two of [this web page](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/sound/play.htm) shows a good example. An easier version of this example would be this...

```
function playSound(soundfile) {
  document.getElementById("sound_element").innerHTML= 
  "<embed src='"+soundfile+"' hidden=true autostart=true loop=false/>";
}
```

The HTML would be this...

```
<span id="sound_element"></span>
```

This puts a hidden embedded file in the web page. You can call this function by doing `playSound(Path/To/File)`

Comment: But I still need Flash or Quicktime (or some plugin) to actually play the sound, right?

Comment: @MattW As far as I know, you need Quicktime to play any media on the web. This shouldn't be a problem.